# Go Test - Junit results

Tags: xml, go, testing, junit, tee

My problem is that I would like to get reports in Junit from Go tests. The problem is that this is not possible natively. I have found several tools that do this, but a problem arises.
I found [go-junit-report](https://github.com/jstemmer/go-junit-report) tool, really good, but i can not use it since:

```
go test -count=1 --run Test ./test/... | tee -a test-output.log
```

For this test execution i've this 'tee' command piped, and this is not compatible with the junit tool:

```
go test -v -bench . -count=1 --run Test ./test/... 2>&1 | go-junit-report > report.xml
```

How can i overcome this? So, having the tee command get executed correctly but also the report in junit?

ps: i found also the [gotestsum](https://github.com/gotestyourself/gotestsum) tool, which would work directly with the pipe command, but this would mean change the test command and maybe also the infrastructure, so not so good.

Comment: "i've this 'tee' command piped, and this is not compatible with the junit tool" What is incompatible with tee and go-junit-report? What did you do and what didn't work out?

Comment: I must premise that I did not write the tests, which is why I do not know exactly the purpose of this "tee". But concatenate the command, it doesn't work (so: go test ... | tee .. | gojunit ..)

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a suitable problem description. Do you have problems with bash and output redirection? Try go test ... 2>&1 | tee .. | gojunit ..

Comment: This is exactly the point. "go test ... 2>&1 | tee .. | gojunit" will not work since the gojunit tool needs the results coming from the go test, so has to be concatened directly. But the same is also for the tee comand, it has to follow directly the go test. And here comes my question. How can i fullfil both conditions? So having tee command executed but also junit?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this.

If gojunit must not see stderr you must not duplicate stderr to stdout with `2>&1` in which case you loos stderr from test-output.log.

You either have to sacrifice stderr output from test-output.log or run `go test` twice, once writing stdout and stderr to test-output.log and once piping thru gojunit.

Answer (score 0):

Can do this in two steps

```
go test -v -covermode=count -coverprofile=coverage.txt ./...  2>&1 | tee coverage.out
go-junit-report < coverage.out > report.xml
```